# Update UICollectionViewFlowLayout without creating a new UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I would like to update certain the UICollectionViewFlowLayout or a UICollectionView because I want to set the size of the cells to a specific number that needs to be calculated (screenwidth / 3) - 2.
However, I only know how to assign it by creating a new instance which would reset lots of properties and force me to redefine them. Can this be updated some where else? Or is there a good way to just update ItemSize?

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
      SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, 0),
      MinimumInteritemSpacing = 2,
      MinimumLineSpacing = 2,
      ItemSize = new SizeF(Size, Size),
      ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical,
};
ProfilesListView = new UICollectionView(ProfilesListView.Frame, layout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to initialize `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` again when you want to set the item's size. You can use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to programmatically modify the size:

```
public class MyCollectionDelegate : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    public override CGSize GetSizeForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return new CGSize(Size, Size);
    }
}
```

After setting this Delegate to your UICollectionView: `ProfilesListView.Delegate = new MyCollectionDelegate();`

You can modify it through changing the event `GetSizeForItem()` and forcing updating the UICollectionView `ProfilesListView.ReloadData();`